# How To Create Xml File and open that immediately in windows-App C#?

Tags: c#, xml, windows

I have a windows application with C#.
I want to create an xml file and then open it with .xml extension.
but I don't know how I can do that?

this is a sample code:

```
 string xmlString = null;
       using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
       {
           XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
           writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented; 

           writer.WriteStartDocument(); 
           writer.WriteStartElement("TAG"); 

           writer.WriteStartElement("SUBTAG");
           writer.WriteString("value");
           writer.WriteEndElement();

           writer.WriteStartElement("SUBTAG");
           writer.WriteStartAttribute("attr");
           writer.WriteString("hello");
           writer.WriteEndAttribute();
           writer.WriteString("world");
           writer.WriteEndElement();

           writer.WriteEndElement(); 
           writer.WriteEndDocument();

           xmlString = sw.ToString();
       }


       XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
       xdoc.LoadXml(xmlString);
```

Comment: What is the problem here? It seems that your code is correct. Are you just asking how to show the data contained in the xdoc variable?

Comment: yes. I want To show a Xml File. but xdoc.Load doesnt show any file.

Comment: xdoc.OuterXml returns a string with your content.

Comment: you want to open inside some other editor? like notepad?

Comment: I want to open that file such a xml file with extension .xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the XML. It's not too clear what you want to achieve but you can do a few different things.

1. To display the contents you can simply put a rich textbox or something similar and set the text property

   ```
   richTextBox1.Text = xmlString;
   ```

[image]

2. You can save the XML to a file like this:

   ```
   File.WriteAllText("output.xml", xmlString);
   ```
3. If you want to display the contents of the file, you can read and display from the file like this:

   ```
   richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText("output.xml");
   ```
4. If you want to open the file in notepad you can run it as a separate process:

   ```
   Process.Start("notepad.exe", "output.xml");
   ```
5. If you want to open the file with the default application you can run it like this:

   ```
   Process.Start("output.xml");
   ```

Depending on the way you want to go just replace the XmlDocument lines with the one above as you don't need XmlDocument at this point.